# How to get page number of a tag in tagged pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to get the page number of a tag in tagged PDF.

I have tried below code but I'm not sure.

```
for(Object coDic: structElement.getKids()) {
   int page=((PDStructureElement) coDic).getCOSObject().getCOSDictionary(COSName.PG).getInt(COSName.STRUCT_PARENTS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

structParents is something completely different (see [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)). Do this:

```
PDPage page = new PDPage(((PDStructureElement) coDic).getCOSObject().getCOSDictionary(COSName.PG));
int pageNum = doc.getPages().indexOf(page);
```

or better:

```
PDPage page = ((PDStructureElement) coDic).getPage();
int pageNum = doc.getPages().indexOf(page);
```

(null checks and class checks omitted)